# Should I use DISTINCT?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a program that report its version and IP to the following table

```
CREATE TABLE `Operadores` (
  `Num` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Usuario` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `LastLogin` varchar(25) DEFAULT '01/01/1970 00:00:00',
  `AdminLevel` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '1',
  `Grupo` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Operadores',
  `Version` varchar(20) DEFAULT 'OLD',
  `NombrePC` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LastIP` varchar(16) DEFAULT '0.0.0.0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Num`,`Usuario`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Num_UNIQUE` (`Num`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Usuario_UNIQUE` (`Usuario`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=55 DEFAULT CHARSET=l
```

The version is saved as 1.5.4.3, and I use only one digit between dots; so bigger number means bigger version.

I need to make a query, in MySQL Workbench, to know the bigger version of each IP.

Example:
If the last version is 1.6.0.2 and I have the following data

```
Usuario Version   LastIP
Mike     1.6.0.1  10.0.1.1
Eric     1.6.0.2  10.0.1.1
Adam     1.1.0.1  10.0.1.2
Clark    1.6.0.2  10.0.1.2
Kirk     1.6.0.0  10.0.1.3
```

I should obtain

```
Usuario Version   LastIP
Eric     1.6.0.2  10.0.1.1
Clark    1.6.0.2  10.0.1.2
Kirk     1.6.0.0  10.0.1.3
```

So now I can see that Kirk on PC 10.0.1.3 is using an old version of the software.

I already tried with

```
SELECT * FROM gts.Operadores GROUP BY VersionGTS,LastIP ORDER BY LastLogin DESC;
```

But I obtain one row by every record, and I just want one result(the biggest version) for each IP.

Comment: SELECT max(version),lasIP FROM t GROUP BY lasIP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you are getting two rows is because you are using two columns in your `group by` clause `VersionGTS,LastIP`.

If you want to get only one value then you can use the `max` function to get the max version of the `Version` column try this:

```
SELECT max(versionGTS),LastIP,LastLogin 
FROM gts.Operadores 
GROUP BY LastIP,LastLogin 
ORDER BY LastLogin DESC;
```

Comment: `ORDER BY LastLogin`? You aren't pulling `LastLogin`.

Comment: @AndriyM:- Yes, as I was focussed on the trouble part. But good pick. Updated. Thanks :)

Comment: Uh-oh, now you are pulling `LastLogin` but are not grouping by it. Oh the perverted things MySQL lets you do with GROUP BY...

Comment: Hmm, now your query would likely return different results (max version per IP *and* last login time, which is not the same as max version per IP only). I realise this mess is partly my doing, I'm sorry. The problem is the OP accepted a non-working query without commenting on how they used it. My guess is they added `LastLogin` as you did [here](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25730488/4). (Counter to the way things should be done in standard SQL, yes, but this is MySQL, what can we do?) That or they got rid of the ORDER BY all together.

Answer (score 1):

To get the maximum version per IP, you can use this simple query:

```
SELECT
  MAX(Version) AS MaxVersion,
  LastIP
FROM
  gts.Operadores
GROUP BY
  LastIP
;
```

If you want to additionally return `Usuario` associated with every particular pair of `MaxVersion` and `LastIP`, you can achieve that by joining the results back to `gts.Operadores`:

```
SELECT
  o.Usuario,
  o.Version,
  o.LastIP
FROM
  gts.Operadores AS o
INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      MAX(Version) AS MaxVersion,
      LastIP
    FROM
      gts.Operadores
    GROUP BY
      LastIP
  ) AS m
ON
  o.LastIP = m.LastIP
  AND o.Version = m.MaxVersion
;
```

If a user logs in from the same IP and with the same version which happens to be the maximum one for that IP, the above query will return duplicate entries. It is easy eliminate them with a `DISTNCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  o.Usuario,
  o.Version,
  o.LastIP
FROM
  gts.Operadores AS o
INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      MAX(Version) AS MaxVersion,
      LastIP
    FROM
      gts.Operadores
    GROUP BY
      LastIP
  ) AS m
ON
  o.LastIP = m.LastIP
  AND o.Version = m.MaxVersion
;
```

However, if multiple users share the same IP, the last query might still give you multiple rows per IP. If you insist on getting only one row for every IP and you insist on having a (corresponding) `Usuario` coming with every row, you should specify which row you want. For instance, you could pick the maximum `Usuario` per (maximum) version and IP:

```
SELECT
  MAX(o.Usuario) AS Usuario,
  o.Version,
  o.LastIP
FROM
  gts.Operadores AS o
INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      MAX(Version) AS MaxVersion,
      LastIP
    FROM
      gts.Operadores
    GROUP BY
      LastIP
  ) AS m
ON
  o.LastIP = m.LastIP
  AND o.Version = m.MaxVersion
GROUP BY
  o.Version,
  o.LastIP
;
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you did something along the lines of (pardon the syntax I am winging it)

```
SELECT MAX(CONVERT(IP, INT))  -- Have to strip out the periods and use it as an INT I would suppose
FROM gts.operadores
GROUP BY USUARIO
```

Should give the max value IP for each group

Comment: I need the max value of Version, not LastIP. I need one result by each different LastIP.

Comment: @E_Blue:- Are you not getting the result with the query which I posted in my answer?

Comment: When I post my comment I didn't test your query, I just read what do you are trying to do. Now I tried and MySQL Workbench remarks me the word INT.